# Show a warning modal on click of buttons other than in the current component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which has all the form fields. Once one of the fields are filled, I have to show a warning popup to the user when they try to click any other buttons on the screen which are not a part of the current component where the fields are present.

I tried the below code with useEffect but I think there is fundamentally something wrong with this approach.

```
useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            setOpenPopup(true);
        }
}, [])
```

I have a modal which will open when the state value of openPopup is true.

Answer (score 0):

You're 100% correct, this is a fundamental mistake :)

Your code only executes once, before component will be unmounted, hence the modal that is inside of this component will never be shown, as you're trying to show it, just before deleting the whole component from DOM

Comment: Keep in mind that this WOULD work, if the setOpenPopup function would be passed in props and some parent component would be responsible for hiding/showing component AND it would not unmount when this child component unmounts :)